# Understand the PasswordAuthentication in sshd configuration

Tags: password, authentication, sshd

I have an OpenSSH server which supports only password authentication:

```
[martin@ ~]$ ssh -v 10.10.1.183 -l root
OpenSSH_5.2p1 FreeBSD-20090522, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.1.183 [10.10.1.183] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/identity type 0
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2p1 FreeBSD-20090522
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.10.1.183' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/martin/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@10.10.1.183's password:
```

In other words only the `PasswordAuthentication` in server `sshd_config` file is set to `yes`.

According to [RFC 4252](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4252.txt) section 8 `It is up to the server how to interpret the password and validate it against the password database.` Am I correct that in Linux this means that `sshd` directly checks the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files if `UsePAM` in `sshd` configuration is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct that in Linux this means that sshd directly checks the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files if UsePAM in sshd configuration is disabled?

Yes. But currently most of distributions handle login using pam, because the sessions in todays systems are getting more and more complicated. OpenSSH can communicate with shadow using `<shadow.h>` header file and functions defined in there.

For more information, this is in source code files `auth.c` and `auth-shadow.c`

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the source indicates that auth-passwd.c includes <pwd.h> & auth-shadow.c includes <shadow.h>. Without doing to deep of a dive, it seems that sshd does use the system calls to check the password. There was also code that allowed sshd to required and do a password change for expired passwords.